# Lucene 4.3 Delete

Tags: lucene

I've got a problem with deleting documents from my `LuceneIndex`. For my delete I've used a termquery. After I noticed that the docs are not deleted, I tried to search for the docs first and no docs are found.

I store my Documents like this:

```
  public boolean storeNote(Note note) throws Exception {

        Document doc = new Document();

        this.initalizeWriter(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
        if (note != null && note.getUri() != null && note.getPatientUri() != null && !note.getUri().isEmpty()
                && !note.getPatientUri().isEmpty()) {

            doc.add(new TextField(URINOTE, note.getUri(), Field.Store.YES));
            doc.add(new TextField(URIPATIENT, note.getPatientUri(), Field.Store.YES));

            if (note.getTitle() != null && !note.getTitle().isEmpty()) {
                doc.add(new TextField(NOTETITLE, note.getTitle(), Field.Store.YES));
            }

            if (note.getText() != null && !note.getText().isEmpty()) {
                doc.add(new TextField(NOTETEXT, note.getText(), Field.Store.YES));
            }

        }

        try 
        {
        this.writer.addDocument(doc);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LOGGER.info("DocSave Failed \n" + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure that index is closed. Open indexFiles are locked!
            this.closeWriter();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

After storing the docs into my index there comes the time to delete it which I try this way:

```
 public boolean deleteNote(Note note) throws IOException
    {
        if(note == null || note .getUri() == null || note.getUri().isEmpty() )   
                return false;

            LOGGER.info("Deleting Notes with URI '" + note.getPatientUri());

            TermQuery deleteTerm = new TermQuery(new Term(URINOTE, note.getUri()));

            try
            {
                this.initalizeWriter(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
                this.writer.deleteDocuments(deleteTerm);      
                this.writer.commit();
                LOGGER.info("Deleting for '" + note.getUri() + "done");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                this.writer.rollback();
                LOGGER.info("Rollback for '" + note.getPatientUri() + "done \n");
                LOGGER.info("Check Consitenzy");
            }
            finally
            {
               this.closeWriter();
            }
            return true;
    }

String queryString = URIPATIENT + ":\"" + request.getPatientUri() + "\"";

        Query query = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43, NOTETEXT, analyzer).parse(queryString);
```

My Problem is that my deleteTerm does not return any results. I tried it by searching by my deleteTerm.

Any Idea what I missed there?

Answer (score 1):

For the id of your document you should use something 'not tokenized'.
You should use 'StringField' ,documentation says:

> StringField: A field that is indexed but not tokenized: the entire  String
>   value is indexed as a single token.

Then delete should be invoked by a single term(you don't need a query).

```
doc.add(new StringField(URINOTE, note.getUri(), Field.Store.YES));
....
this.writer.deleteDocuments(new Term(URINOTE, note.getUri()));
```

That should work.